# PHP: JSON Log Data For A Persons Activity With Timestamp, How To Count It?

Tags: php, json

My JSON looks like this:

```
[{"NAME":"Burger Man","USER_ID":"14","TIMESTAMP":"1367668271","ACTION":"enabled"},    
{"NAME":"Test McTest","USER_ID":"16","TIMESTAMP":"1368092635","ACTION":"disabled"},
{"NAME":"Test McTest","USER_ID":"16","TIMESTAMP":"1368132268","ACTION":"enabled"}]
```

From this data I want to count the number of days a person is active up until the current date. If a person is found only once in this data it means he is active for the whole time and for the persons who are found more than once I have to count their activity time in some way.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
$workers2 = array();
foreach($data as $mydata){
  $workers2[] = array($mydata->NAME, $mydata->ACTION, date('Y-m-d h:i:s',$mydata->TIMESTAMP));
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($workers2);
echo '</pre>';
```

Outputs the following:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Burger Man
        [1] => enabled
        [2] => 2013-05-04 02:51:11
    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [0] => Test McTest
        [1] => disabled
        [2] => 2013-05-09 12:43:55
    )

[19] => Array
    (
        [0] => Test McTest
        [1] => enabled
        [2] => 2013-05-09 11:44:28
    )

)
```

I figure I got to insert all the names in an array and check for duplicates. If there is no duplicate for a certain name, I know he is active for the whole time. Also a person can be activated and disabled at any time. How can I get every persons combined activity time from this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't just add them to the new array at the end. Specify the index so you can check for duplicates.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
$workers2 = array();
foreach($data as $mydata){
  if(!isset($workers2[$mydata->USER_ID])) {
     $workers2[$mydata->USER_ID] = array($mydata->NAME, $mydata->ACTION, date('Y-m-d h:i:s',$mydata->TIMESTAMP));
  }
}
```

You can further filter the data as you need*, but this gives the general idea.

* - in other words you can also test whether the new timestamp is new or older than the one currently saved and replace if necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up constructing an array in the following way: $workers2[$mydata->USER_ID][] = array(
        'USER_ID' => $mydata->USER_ID,
        'NAME'    => $mydata->NAME,
        'ACTION'  => $mydata->ACTION,
        'TIMESTAMP' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $mydata->TIMESTAMP)
      );